# To identify overlapping lines between 2 shape file using GDAL

Tags: gdal, c#

I have 2 shape files in and I have to identify the overlapping lines between 2 shape lines. I have tried below code using overlap, It provided me non-overlapping lines as well.

```
while ((jsonFeature = layer.GetNextFeature()) != null)
        {
            var gdef = jsonFeature.GetGeometryRef();
            layer1.ResetReading();

            while ((jsonFeature1 = layer1.GetNextFeature()) != null)
            {

                gdef1 = jsonFeature.GetGeometryRef();

                isoverlapp = gdef1.Overlaps(gdef);


                if (isoverlapp == true)
                {
                    Console.Write("True");
                }

            }
   }
```